# Calculating the mapping degree of a function:

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S^{2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be the 2-sphere and 
$$f:S^{2}\to S^{2}$$
$$(x,y,z)^{T}\mapsto \frac{(x^{2}-y^{2},2xy,z)^{T}}{\Vert (x^{2}-y^{2},2xy,z)^{T}\Vert_{2}}$$

My goal is to calculate the mapping degree $\mathrm{deg}(f)$. For this, I should show before that $p:=(1,0,0)^{T}$ is regular value of $f$.

For this, I have to show that the differential $d_{q}f$ is for all $q\in f^{-1}(\{p\})=\{p_{-},p_{+}\}$ with $p_{\pm}=(\pm 1,0,0)^{T}$ is surjective.

After some long but straightforward calculation I get 
$$\partial_{x}f(p_{\pm})=(0,0,0)^{T}$$
$$\partial_{y}f(p_{\pm})=(0,\pm 2,0)^{T}$$
$$\partial_{z}f(p_{\pm})=(0,0,1)^{T}$$

Now to my questions:

(1) How can I calculate now the differential $d_{p_{\pm}}f:T_{p_{\pm}}S^{2}\to T_{f(p_{\pm})}S^{2}=T_{p}S^{2}$?

My Ansatz here is to say that the vectors $\partial_{y},\partial_{z}$ are a basis of $T_{p_{\pm}}S^{2}$. Then I see that

$$d_{p_{\pm}}f(\partial_{y})=\pm 2\partial_{y} \hspace{0.5cm}\mathrm{and}\hspace{0.5cm}d_{p_{\pm}}f(\partial_{z})=\partial_{z}.$$

Is this the right way? If yes then the differentials are obviously surjective, because I can find for every vector $v=v_{y}\partial_{y}+v_{z}\partial_{z}\in T_{p}S^{2}$ a element $w=\pm \frac{v_{y}}{2}\partial_{y}+v_{z}\partial_{z}$ such that $d_{p_{\pm}}f(w)=v$.....

(2) How can I now calculate the mapping degree? The mapping degree is defined as $\mathrm{deg}(f)=r-s$, where $r$ is the number of element in $f^{-1}(\{p\})$, where the differential is orientation conserving and $s$ the number, where the differential switches the orientation....

Comment: Do you know that the mapping degree can be determined by considering the map $f_* : H_2(S^2) \to H_2(S^2)$?